# How do you iterate over continuous subsequences of a slice that contain equal elements?

Tags: rust, iterator, slice

I have a sequence of elements of a type which implements `PartialEq` in a slice. For illustration, let's say it looks like this:

```rust
let data = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,6];
```

I would like to iterate over borrowed slices of this sequence such that all elements of such slices are equal as per `PartialEq`. For example in the above slice `data` I would like an iterator which yields:

```
&data[0..3]   // [1,1,1]
&data[3..5]   // [2,2]
&data[5..6]   // [3]
&data[6..7]   // [4]
&data[7..11]  // [5,5,5,5]
&data[11..12] // [6]
```

It looks like [slice::group_by](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.group_by) is exactly what I need, but as of Rust 1.72.0, it is not yet stable. Is there any straightforward way to get this functionality in a stable way, either by use of a 3rd party crate or by combining the use of stable std lib APIs?

Comment: You can use [group_by](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.11.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) from the itertools crate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group_by` is a pretty simple function. It returns an iterator with [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/iter.rs.html#3268-3281) `next` implementation:

```rs
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    if self.slice.is_empty() {
        None
    } else {
        let mut len = 1;
        let mut iter = self.slice.windows(2);
        while let Some([l, r]) = iter.next() {
            if (self.predicate)(l, r) { len += 1 } else { break }
        }
        let (head, tail) = self.slice.split_at(len);
        self.slice = tail;
        Some(head)
    }
}
```

Since you have a simple predicate, you can make an iterator with [`from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html) that's even shorter.

```rs
fn group_by<T: PartialEq>(mut slice: &[T]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &[T]> + '_ {
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        let first = slice.first()?;
        let len = slice.iter().position(|t| first != t).unwrap_or(slice.len());
        let (head, tail) = slice.split_at(len);
        slice = tail;
        Some(head)
    })
}
```

The only difference between this and calling `group_by(|a, b| a == b)` is that this one checks equality with the first element, which may give different results for non-`Eq` types. You can return to the `windows` method from the nightly `group_by` if this matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the subgroups as slices, but as something iterable, you can use [`Itertools::group_by()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) from the itertools crate:

```
let data = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6];

for (_k, group) in &data.iter().group_by(|&k| k) {
    println!("{:?}", group.collect_vec());
}
```

The `group` object is documented not to allocate if you don't keep multiple groups from the same iterator around at the same time.

[Plaground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a31a6801430edc47f2d927ebc08d01e)